# Cannot upload image to Paperclip from Rails: #<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError:

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, heroku, imagemagick, paperclip

First of all, I am running Rails 4 on Heroku.

I am building an API for uploading images, using the Paperclip gem.

The api endpoint uses a param 'image' for the raw bytes of the file to upload.

The code to upload to Paperclip looks like this:

```
contents = input['image']

file = Tempfile.new('foo')
file.write(contents)

attachment = {
    :filename => 'test',
    :type => 'test',
    :headers => 'image',
    :tempfile => file
}
image = ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.new(attachment)
```

The image raw file bytes (produced by an Android app) from the heroku logs looks like this:

```
2015-06-03T00:40:01.153210+00:00 app[web.1]: 8ijJz0r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\nsPDqaZoltLrUOnpgz3jIDLK/qzOSxz3NfyE/8EAf2abz43/t
```

Followed by

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

That string was created by this line of Java code:

```
String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Anyone know what's going on here?